# Nested Key/Value Structures in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, lodash

I get the following JSON Structure from a service:

```
{
    "prop": [
        {
            "key": "FOO",
            "value": "Foo is wonderfull, foo is great"
        },
        {
            "key": "BAR",
            "value": "Bar is bad, really bad"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need a function, which takes as parameter e.g. BAR and outputs "Bar is bad,..", how can I achieve that? Lodash/underscore or VanillaJS are welcome.

Comment: You can loop over your `prop` array and get the `key` property in each interation, compare it with the argument passed to your function and return the `value` property if it matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.find` to find necessary object and then return its value

```js
var d = {
  "prop": [{
    "key": "FOO",
    "value": "Foo is wonderfull, foo is great"
  }, {
    "key": "BAR",
    "value": "Bar is bad, really bad"
  }]
}

function FindValue(value) {
  var _tmp = d.prop.find(function(o) {
    return o.key === value
  });
  return _tmp ? _tmp.value : "No object found";
}

console.log(FindValue("BAR"));
console.log(FindValue("BAR1"));
console.log(FindValue("FOO"));
```

---

#### Edit 1

As suggested by [@Benny Bottema](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441662/benny-bottema), `Array.find` has compatibility issues. You can either add a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) or you can use other methods like `Array.filter`  and `Array.forEach` but note, even these methods are not supported in IE8.

If you which to make it compatible with all browsers, you should use `for` or `for..in` as they are standard across browsers.

**For version**

```js
var d = {
  "prop": [{
    "key": "FOO",
    "value": "Foo is wonderfull, foo is great"
  }, {
    "key": "BAR",
    "value": "Bar is bad, really bad"
  }]
}

function FindValue(value) {
  for (var i=0;i<d.prop.length;i++){
    if(d.prop[i].key === value) return d.prop[i].value;
  }
}

console.log(FindValue("BAR"));
console.log(FindValue("BAR1"));
console.log(FindValue("FOO"));
```

---

**for..in version**

Note, `for..in` is more suited to loop over keys of object.

```js
var d = {
  "prop": [{
    "key": "FOO",
    "value": "Foo is wonderfull, foo is great"
  }, {
    "key": "BAR",
    "value": "Bar is bad, really bad"
  }]
}

function FindValue(value) {
  for (var i in d.prop){
    if(d.prop[i].key === value) return d.prop[i].value;
  }
}

console.log(FindValue("BAR"));
console.log(FindValue("BAR1"));
console.log(FindValue("FOO"));
```

---

**for..of version**

If you are using ES6, then you can even try [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```js
var d = {
  "prop": [{
    "key": "FOO",
    "value": "Foo is wonderfull, foo is great"
  }, {
    "key": "BAR",
    "value": "Bar is bad, really bad"
  }]
}

function FindValue(value) {
  for (var _o of d.prop){
    if(_o.key === value) return _o.value;
  }
}

console.log(FindValue("BAR"));
console.log(FindValue("BAR1"));
console.log(FindValue("FOO"));
```

---

#### References

- [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [Array.find - compatibility - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: `Array.find` is [not properly supported by major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility) and requires a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill).

Comment: @BennyBottema Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated my answer. Hope it resolves it. Please mention if anything is still missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
var filteredArray = { "prop": [{ "key": "FOO", "value": "Foo is wonderfull, foo is great" }, { "key": "BAR", "value": "Bar is bad, really bad" }] };
function getByKey(findKey,filteredArray){
    if(filteredArray.length){
            var result = filteredArray.filter(function(x){
                return x.key === findKey
            });
            if(result && result.length){return result[0].value}
    }
}
getByKey('BAR',filteredArray.prop)
```

But the function will only return the first filtered Object's value;

Answer (score 0):

I am writing it in JAVASCRIPT:

```js
var d = {
  "prop": [{
    "key": "FOO",
    "value": "Foo is wonderfull, foo is great"
  }, {
    "key": "BAR",
    "value": "Bar is bad, really bad"
  }]
}

obj = d;
parm = 'BAR'
for (item in obj["prop"]) {
  if (parm == item['key']) {
    console.log(item['value'])
  }
}
```

Steps to look:-

- First parse JSON to Object
- Then Iterate over "prop"
- Compare key with param ("BAR")
- If matches print value

Comment: This won't work as for..in loop iterates the properties of an object. If it's an array, `item` in each iteration will be the numerical index in a string like `"0"` or `"1" ` not the actual object in the array

Comment: @Arkantos here prop is a array and it works perfectly. Try it out. If it didn't work down vote it.

Comment: @RakeshKumar Just updated your answer. Just check and make necessary changes. Also as Arkantos is correct. It should be `obj["prop"][item]["key"]` or use `for...of`

Comment: @RakeshKumar.. It doesn't work. Here's a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mExrKg?editors=1010) with your code. Like I said, it prints 0 and 1.

Comment: @Arkantos I guess he tried `for..of` but while writing, he types `for..in`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Modern pure javascript:

```
function getValue(theObject, keyValue) {
  return theObject.prop
    .filter(function(x){ // find all elements with the wanted key
      return x.key == keyValue;
    })
    .map(function(x){ // return only the value
      return x.value;
    })[0]; // Assuming no duplicate keys just return first item
}
```

Note: The array methods `.filter()` and `.map()` return arrays.

#### Old-school for loop:

```
function getValue(theObject, keyValue) {
  var p = theObject.prop;

  for (var i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
    var item = p[i];
    if (item.key == keyValue) {
      return item.value;
    }
  }
}
```

Interestingly, this is faster than the first method above because it stops processing the `prop` array as soon as it finds a match.

Comment: If you are returning `[0]` element, why `map` in the first place. Just check if object exists and return `_temp[0].value`

Comment: I was trying your solution, with Angular2 + Observables and could not get the "FOO": http://plnkr.co/edit/JMvZ2pNhjpzS7bG6erWb?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lodash#find](https://lodash.com/docs#find) to get the value by key.

```
function getValueByKey(array, key) {
  return (_.find(array, { key: key }) || {}).value;
}

var result = getValueByKey(data.prop, 'BAR');
```

```js
var data = {
    "prop": [
        {
            "key": "FOO",
            "value": "Foo is wonderfull, foo is great"
        },
        {
            "key": "BAR",
            "value": "Bar is bad, really bad"
        }
    ]
};

function getValueByKey(array, key) {
  return (_.find(array, { key: key }) || {}).value;
}

var result = getValueByKey(data.prop, 'BAR');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

**Lodash**

```js
var data = {
    "prop": [
        {
            "key": "FOO",
            "value": "Foo is wonderfull, foo is great"
        },
        {
            "key": "BAR",
            "value": "Bar is bad, really bad"
        }
    ]
}

function getValueForKey(key) {
  return _.result(_.find(data.prop, { key: key }), 'value') || "unknown key: " + key;
}

document.write(getValueForKey("FOO") + "<br/>");
document.write(getValueForKey("BAR") + "<br/>");
document.write(getValueForKey("FOOBAR"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/4.13.1/dist/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

**Underscore**

```js
var data = {
    "prop": [
        {
            "key": "FOO",
            "value": "Foo is wonderfull, foo is great"
        },
        {
            "key": "BAR",
            "value": "Bar is bad, really bad"
        }
    ]
}

function getValueForKey(key) {
  return _.result(_.find(data.prop, { key: key }), 'value', "unknown key: " + key);
}

document.write(getValueForKey("FOO") + "<br/>");
document.write(getValueForKey("BAR") + "<br/>");
document.write(getValueForKey("FOOBAR"));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
```

**Plain javascript** (using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), supported by major browsers)

```js
var data = {
    "prop": [
        {
            "key": "FOO",
            "value": "Foo is wonderfull, foo is great"
        },
        {
            "key": "BAR",
            "value": "Bar is bad, really bad"
        }
    ]
}

function getValueForKey(key) {
  var prop = data.prop.filter(function(prop) { return prop.key === key})[0];
  return prop ? prop.value : "unknown key: " + key;
}

document.write(getValueForKey("FOO") + "<br/>");
document.write(getValueForKey("BAR") + "<br/>");
document.write(getValueForKey("FOOBAR"));
```

**Plain javascript** (using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), currently mostly works with polyfill)

```js
var data = {
    "prop": [
        {
            "key": "FOO",
            "value": "Foo is wonderfull, foo is great"
        },
        {
            "key": "BAR",
            "value": "Bar is bad, really bad"
        }
    ]
}

function getValueForKey(key) {
  var prop = data.prop.find(function(prop) { return prop.key === key });
  return prop ? prop.value : "unknown key: " + key;
}

document.write(getValueForKey("FOO") + "<br/>");
document.write(getValueForKey("BAR") + "<br/>");
document.write(getValueForKey("FOOBAR"));
```

```html
<script>
// polyfill from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Array.prototype.find = function(predicate) {
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  };
}
</script>
```

**Plain javascript** (using old school for-loop)

```js
var data = {
    "prop": [
        {
            "key": "FOO",
            "value": "Foo is wonderfull, foo is great"
        },
        {
            "key": "BAR",
            "value": "Bar is bad, really bad"
        }
    ]
}

function getValueForKey(key) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.prop.length; i++) {
    if (data.prop[i].key === key) {
      return data.prop[i].value;
    }
    return "unknown key: " + key;
  }
}

document.write(getValueForKey("FOO") + "<br/>");
document.write(getValueForKey("BAR") + "<br/>");
document.write(getValueForKey("FOOBAR"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and end the iteration if the value is found.

```js
function getValue(array, key) {
    var value;
    array.some(function (a) {
        if (a.key === key) {
            value = a.value;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return value;
}

var object = { "prop": [{ "key": "FOO", "value": "Foo is wonderfull, foo is great" }, { "key": "BAR", "value": "Bar is bad, really bad" }] };

console.log(getValue(object.prop, 'BAR'));
```

ES6 with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
function getValue(array, key) {
    return (array.find(a => a.key === key) || {}).value;
}

var object = { "prop": [{ "key": "FOO", "value": "Foo is wonderfull, foo is great" }, { "key": "BAR", "value": "Bar is bad, really bad" }] };

console.log(getValue(object.prop, 'BAR'));
```

Comment: @Rajesh, rigth. therfore a default object : `(array.find(a => a.key === key) || {}).value;`